# Kotlin - Type mismatch: required: Context found: Context?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to make a PopupMenu

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    menu_btn.setOnClickListener {
        var menu: PopupMenu?
        menu = PopupMenu(this.context, it)
        menu.inflate(R.menu.card_menu)

        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_modify -> { Toast.makeText(context, "Modify", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    true }

                R.id.menu_delete -> { Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    true }

                else -> false
            }
        }

        menu.show()
    }
}
```

but I get wiggly red line under

```
menu = PopupMenu(this.context, it)
```

That says: 
Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
Contex?

and even when I use !! - I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.emek1.myapplication.FragmentOne.onCreate(FragmentOne.kt:24)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
```

Note: that it's not in MainActivity.kt
It's a Fragment.

Comment: If its fragment you can not "menu_btn.setOnClickListener" in onCreate method. As view will not be initialized there. Try adding this method in "onCreateView" method after inflating view.

Comment: `menu_btn` is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 7):

Write this code

```
context?.let {
    menu = PopupMenu(it, view)
}
```

Here view will be your anchor view of the popup.

instead of

```
menu = PopupMenu(this.context, it)
```

Answer (score 4):

If it was a fragment you should call context like this.

`menu = PopupMenu(activity!!, it)`

or if you have the latest library you can do something like this

`menu = PopupMenu(requireActivity(), it)`

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` arises from fact that `onCreate()` runs before `onCreateView()` which inflates your view hierarchy. Therefore `menu_btn` is still null, because not found. Have another look at the [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating) lifecycle.

For the popup it might be better to use the `Context` from the `View` parameter `it.context`.