# In this code contex not working required: Context found: Context?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class Add : Fragment()
{

val types = arrayOf("simple User", "Admin")

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val t=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)
        val spinner = t.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner2)
       spinner?.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity?.applicationContext, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, types) as SpinnerAdapter
        spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object :AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                println("erreur")
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val type = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(activity,type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                println(type)
            }

        }
        return t
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - Type mismatch: required: Context found: Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753000/kotlin-type-mismatch-required-context-found-context)

Answer (score 0):

Its required non-null Context object (Context class) and you give nullable Context object (Context? class). You can manually cast it to non-null with operator !! `context!!`, and it will work if `context != null` (`activity!!.applicationContext!!` in your case). But it is not the best practic, because if it is null, you can get NPE. So better wrap your code with

```
if (activity!= null && activity.applicationContext != null) {
//your code with context cast (activity!!.applicationContext!!)
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using if, you should be using `let?`

Comment: Yes, it is more laconic solution. but i wanted OP to understand what we actually checking :)

Comment: If you understand the Fragment lifecycle, it should be fine to use requireContext() in this situation because the context cannot possibly be null in onCreateView(). That is preferable to wrapping code you know should always run in an if statement that suggests that it might not run. In a situation like this, an NPE would be preferable to silently doing nothing because it would alert you to any coding error immediately the first time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

getActivity returns a Activity? and you should get a Activity without null

Use a requireActivity() or activity!!

Comment: As we can see in the Kotlin documentation - Like NPE? Use !!. It is very bad practice, because it destroys the null-safety of Kotlin.

Comment: In debug mode, you should catch an exception to avoid errors in the program code. If you use activity !!, your application will crash and make you think about the correctness of the logic. requireActivity () an equivalent entry with an activity !!

Comment: `In debug mode, you should catch an exception to avoid errors in the program code` better yet, just code so you don't have exceptions. don't use unsafe casts